# calculate the columns adding the value of the previous row and initial value of column is zero in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am struggling a little, not to say, much with some SQL logic.

What I want to do is the following:
For example,
Balance initial value is zero.

```
Debit   Credit  Balance
0       20      20
5        0      15
1        0      14
1        0      13
0       15      28
```

I hope this is understandable. Please keep it basic when giving an answer, thanks in advance!

Comment: add result that you expect

Comment: debit and credit column is input..and balance is the output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could use Analytical function.

```
with your_table (debit,credit,rn) as
(
select 0,20,1 from dual
union 
select 5,0,2 from dual
union
select 1,0,3 from dual
union 
select 1,0,4 from dual
union
select 0,15,5 from dual
)
SELECT DEBIT,CREDIT, sum(credit-debit) over( order by rn )
from your_table;
```

> [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7)

WIth your actual data, it could be

```
SELECT DEBIT,CREDIT, sum(credit-debit) over( order by <date or somecolumn>)
    from your_table;
```

Simple explanation on Anaytical or WIndow based functions:

> Analytic functions (also known as window functions) are a special
>   category of built-in functions. Like aggregate functions, they examine
>   the contents of multiple input rows to compute each output value.
>   However, rather than being limited to one result value per GROUP BY
>   group, they operate on windows where the input rows are ordered and
>   grouped using flexible conditions expressed through an OVER() clause.

Comment: thank u so much but the column value are changeable..the column values fetch from database

Comment: Updated the answer. It is simple,`WITH` usage is just to simulate the data.